# how to use lodashJs to group a result in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to populate a tree component using angularjs via this JSON object:

```
var myData=[{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","serie":"CZC1448YZN"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Safi","serie":"2UA13817KT"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Rabat","serie":"CZC1349G1B"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Rabat","serie":"  2UA0490SVR"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Agdal","serie":" G3M4NOJ"},{"agence":"CTM","secteur":"Essaouira","serie":" CZC1221B85"},{"agence":"Gare Routiere Municipale","secteur":"Essaouira","serie":" CZC145YL3"}] ;
```

heres the javascript code :

```
var treedata_avm = [];
for(var i=0; i < myData.length; i++) {
   // alert('roro '+myData[i].secteur);
    treedata_avm.push({
        label: myData[i].secteur,
        children: [{
            label: myData.agence,
            children: [myData[i].serie]
        }]
    });
}
 $scope.my_data = treedata_avm;
```

HTML:

```
   <abn-tree tree-data="my_data " tree-control="my_tree" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" expand-level="2" initial-selection="Granny Smith" icon-leaf="ti-file" icon-expand="ti-plus" icon-collapse="ti-minus"></abn-tree>
```

it works fine but i didnt get the expected bevaviour which i want..what i want is to get the data group by secteur and agence like this:

```
-Safi
   -CTM
      CZC1448YZN
      2UA13817KT

-Rabat
  -CTM
     CZC1349G1B
     2UA0490SVR
  -Agdal
     G3M4NOJ

-Essaouira
  -CTM
     CZC1221B85
  -Gare Routiere Municipale
     CZC145YL3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupBy() to initialize the structure as you want:

```
myData = _.groupBy(this.myData, 'secteur');
```

But then you'd have to add in the appropriate extras (agence, serie etc) to each object.

Or you could use _.reduce() which would combine the two (which would probably be better for you). Remember that [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is also a method on arrays in Plain Ol' JavaScript so you're not forced to use lodash:

```
_.reduce(this.myData, function(acc, value, key) {
  (result[key] || result[key] = value).push(acc);
  return acc;
}, acc);
```

Comment: thank u for the answer i tried your second answer but it gives an error in => symbole

Comment: Ahh that's ES6 syntax. Replace () => {} with function() { }

Comment: but what about the loop...i ignore it??

Comment: Yes the reduce will do the loop for you. I'll rewrite it in ES5 syntax to make it less confusing.

Comment: thank u but it doesnt make sens to me...how i can populate the tree???look inside the loop